# Django - better way of multiple if's in template

Tags: django, if-statement, django-templates, refactoring, django-template-filters

I have in template and variables `s1`, `s2`, `s3`

```
<input type="text" value="{% if s1 %}{{s1}}{% endif %}{% if s2 %}{{s2}}{% endif %}{% if s3 %}{{s3}}{% endif %}" />
```

is there better way of doing

```
{% if s1 %}{{s1}}{% endif %}{% if s2 %}{{s2}}{% endif %}{% if s3 %}{{s3}}{% endif %}
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#default) filter:

> If value evaluates to False, uses the given default. Otherwise, uses the value.

```
{{ s1|default:"" }}
```

Comment: so i can say: ``{{s1|default:""}}{{s2|default:""}}{{s3|default:""}}``, right?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **[elif](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#if)** tag.

```
{% if s1 %}{{s1}}{% elif s2 %}{{s2}}{% elif s3 %}{{s3}}{% endif %}
```